# .htaccess redirect URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, wampserver

I am trying to change this:

http://www.test.com/testuser/findUser.php?city=Chennai&txtAreaZip=Annanagar

into

http://www.test.com/testuser/chennai/Annanagar/.

How to redirect above URL to below in .htaccess? I am new in .htaccess. Kindly give your answer for that.

Thanks,
Thamilarasan

Comment: -1 for no research. Also clarify: do you want redirection or rewriting url?

Comment: First link on google: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/ seems to be what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^testuser/(.*)/(.*)/$ testuser/findUser.php?city=$1&txtAreaZip=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Whenever I apply .htaccess, it shows 500 Internal server error. I changed #
    #AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    #It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Whenever I apply .htaccess, it shows 500 Internal server error.  Kindly give your comments to overcome this error?